# Cant disable the controls of my embed video?

Tags: html, css, vbscript, controls

Hello again dear coders,
i have yet another problem, with embedding a video.

The problem is using embed makes it show a lot of controls, and in my eyes does it look like Windows video player. But how do i hide it?

And yes, i have tried reading other forums and links. Tried controls="false", and yet still doenst it "disable" or hide the controls around the video.

**Its a .hta run.**

Here i my code:

```js
<SCRIPT Language="VBScript" Type="text/vbscript">

....

 Sub showPic       'Very crude function to set the image when a triggerfile has been found.
  d1=0

  For Each i in arrTFile
   If objFSO.FileExists(pathCheck & i) Then
    document.getElementById("videoHere").innerHTML="<embed src="& arrFolder(d1) & rndVideo(arrFolder(d1)) &" controls="false">"
    delFile pathCheck & i
  Exit For
   End If
  d1=d1+1
  Next
 End Sub  
  
  </SCRIPT>
```

```css
body {
 background-color:#00FF2F
 }

 .right { 
 position:absolute;
 right:6px;
 bottom:6px
 }

.videos, .videos embed {
width: 75%;
height: 75%;
frameborder: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
  <TITLE>din fars diller</TITLE>
  <hta:application
    id="showVideo"
    applicationName="showVideo"
    border="thin"
    maximizeButton="no"
    minimizeButton="no"
    caption="yes"
    showInTaskBar="yes"
    singleInstance="yes"
    sysMenu="yes"
    scroll="no"
    innerBorder="no"
    contextmenu="no" 
>
</HEAD>

  <BODY>
 <div class="videos" id="videoHere"  class="right"></div>

  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

I look at it like its something in this part of the vb, i have done wrong:

```js
document.getElementById("videoHere").innerHTML="<embed src="& arrFolder(d1) & rndVideo(arrFolder(d1)) &" controls="false">"
```

Here is a picture, where u can see how the controls look like. (the problem)
[image]

Thanks in advance :) <3

Answer (score 0):

```
<OBJECT CLASSID="CLSID:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95" WIDTH="652"
    HEIGHT="382" ID="MediaPlayer1">
<PARAM NAME="AutoStart" VALUE="1">
<PARAM NAME="Filename" VALUE="C:\Users\User\Music\Self Esteem - The offspring.mp4">
<PARAM NAME="ShowControls" VALUE="0">
</OBJECT>
```

Is how I do it.